# I want sum of first three count in range "c5:k5" if count is greater than 0 what should i do?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I want sum of the first three counts in the range "c5:k5" if the count is greater than 0 what should i do?

Answer (score 3):

If one has Office 365:

```
=SUM(INDEX(FILTER(C5:K5,C5:K5>0),0,{1,2,3}))
```

[image]

If not:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDEX(C5:K5,N(IF({1},AGGREGATE(15,7,(COLUMN(C5:K5)-MIN(COLUMN(C5:K5))+1)/(C5:K5>0),{1,2,3})))))
```

[image]